# Отсортировать список участников по алфавиту (runtime error)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Учусь на coursera.
Попалась задача - цитирую:
Известно, что фамилии всех участников — различны. Сохраните в массивах список всех участников и выведите его, отсортировав по фамилии в лексикографическом порядке. При выводе указываете фамилию, имя участника и его балл.

Используйте для ввода и вывода файлы input.txt и output.txt с указанием кодировки utf8. Например, для чтения откройте файл с помощью open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').

Входные данные

Строки вида "Фамилия Имя НомерШколы Балл".

Выходные данные

Строки вида "Фамилия Имя Балл", отсортированные по фамилии.

Примечание

Если у Вас Wrong Answer на первом тесте и в вердикте в качестве правильного ответа показываются знаки вопросов, это не значит, что их действительно нужно выводить. Это баг Курсеры – в вердикте кириллица не поддерживается. Курсера знает о проблеме с 25.10.2018 и возможно починит.

В итоге, при WA на первом тесте не стоит смотреть на вердикт, нужно искать ошибку в решении.

Примеры:

Тест 1
Входные данные:
Иванов Сергей 14 56
Сергеев Петр 23 74
Петров Василий 3 99
Васильев Андрей 3 56
Андреев Роман 14 75
Романов Иван 27 68

Вывод программы:
Андреев Роман 75
Васильев Андрей 56
Иванов Сергей 56
Петров Василий 99
Романов Иван 68
Сергеев Петр 74

Тест 2
Входные данные:
Андреев Роман 14 75
Васильев Андрей 3 56
Иванов Сергей 14 56
Петров Василий 3 99
Романов Иван 27 68
Сергеев Петр 23 74

Вывод программы:
Андреев Роман 75
Васильев Андрей 56
Иванов Сергей 56
Петров Василий 99
Романов Иван 68
Сергеев Петр 74

Тест 3
Входные данные:
Сергеев Петр 23 74
Романов Иван 27 68
Петров Василий 3 99
Иванов Сергей 14 56
Васильев Андрей 3 56
Андреев Роман 14 75

Вывод программы:
Андреев Роман 75
Васильев Андрей 56
Иванов Сергей 56
Петров Василий 99
Романов Иван 68
Сергеев Петр 74

За примеры извиняюсь, какое то странное форматирование(строки согласно "входным данным" - Фамилия Имя НомерШколы Балл

я сделал следующий код:

```
fin = open('input.txt', 'r')
read = fin.readlines()
res = []
for line in read:
    line = line.strip().split()
    res.append(line)
res.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
for i in res:
    print(i[0], i[1], i[3])
fin.close()
```

есть также требование:
Ограничение по времени - 1000 мс
Ограничение по памяти - 65536 кб

Выдает ошибку при проверке- Runtime error
при этом, даже не доходя до вывода. Т.е. ошибка ранее.
Подскажите, где я не прав. Вроде по уму все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что Ваш код выдает такой traceback:

```
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 65: character maps to <undefined>
```

(тут решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233174/12041518)

Далее видим ошибку в несуществующем элементе `i[3]` вот в этой части кода

```
for i in res:
    print(i[0], i[1], i[3])
```

Меняем его на `i[2]` и вот код решения:

```
fin = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
read = fin.readlines()
res = []
for line in read:
    line = line.strip().split()
    res.append(line)
res.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
for i in res:
    print(i[0], i[1], i[2])
fin.close()
```

Comment: К сожалению не согласен. 
Как оказалось, вся проблемы была в том, что у меня в IDE с encoding='utf-8' не происходит компиляция, а выдает как раз подобную ошибку.
В связи с чем я и убрал этот параметр(а при сдаче, забыл добавить).
Также если мы меняем i[3] на i[2], то мы получаем номер школы, вместо балла. Но, ваша наводка все равно помогла)